# Why are the results from log1p(x) and log(x+1) not identical in R?

Tags: r

I expected `log1p(x)` and `log(x+1)` to return the same result, but they are different by 2.775558e-17. Why don't these two functions return identical results? Is one more accurate than the other?

```r
> y <- log({32/123}+1)
> y
#> [1] 0.2312408

> x <- log1p(32/123)
> x
#> [1] 0.2312408

> x==y
#> [1] FALSE

> y-x
#> [1] 2.775558e-17
> sprintf("%a", y-x)
#> [1] "0x1p-55"
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `log1p` exists to improve the numerical accuracy of the calculation of ln(1+x). See, for instance, [this article](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/07/math-library-functions-that-seem-unnecessary/) that gives more explanation for why `log1p` is necessary. They aren't equal *because* `log(1+x)` is, under some circumstances, quite inaccurate, and `log1p` attempts to fix this. `log1p` isn't just shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way how computers do floating point arithmetic. For checking that the value is reasonably near to the other, I recommend you use the [`dplyr::near()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/near.html) function. In this funciton you can also define by how much these values may differ (the tolerance) for you to still accept them as "equal".